# access denied on external mysql from within docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am getting "access denied for user" when I connect to mysql, but only if I do it from within a docker container.

Stack is:

1. Rails 6 application running in a docker container on a Fargate (ECS)
   instance
2. MySQL/Aurora DB (MySQL 8.0.23) on RDS Application
3. load balancer -> target
   group -> Fargate instance (described in #1) Rt 53 DNS
4. (api.mydomain.com) alias pointing to the load balancer

From OUTSIDE the container, eg running locally, I can connect the rails app to the DB, zero problems.

If I hit http://api.mydomain.com , the rails instance logs the following error:
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (Access denied for user 'hcapi'@'172.31.68.126' (using password: YES)). The same is true if I run the docker instance on my local machine.

I've triple checked the user name and password, and also updated the user's host to be 'hcapi'@'%'

User has the mysql_native_password plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed. Still not sure how, honestly. I just tried messing with user permissions a bunch until it worked.